# Use Python module to convert a non-Linux timestamp into total number of seconds?

Tags: python, time

I have a non-standard (non-Linux) timestamp presented as a `str` that needs to be converted to an `int` containing the total number of seconds that are represented there.

My source data looks like this:

`timestr = "1 year 26 weeks 1 day 23 hours 29 minutes"`

I can easily pull the different values out of that string and perform manual calculations, but was hoping one of the time modules could do the math for me. I just can't find any examples of needing this particular calculation since I don't care about epoch or any date-time representation for my data.

Taking that sample above, in my code I was planning to assign the values accordingly:

```
years=1
weeks=26
days=1
hours=23
minutes=29
```

The answer in this case is `47431740` total seconds.

Comment: Will it strictly follow this pattern?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep!

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I don't think any of the built-in functions would help. But this seems pretty straightforward, no? `years*31540000 + weeks*604800 + days*86400 + 3600*hours + minutes*60`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep something like that is pretty clean, thanks. I guess I assumed with all of the various methods that datetime and other modules have, it would have this built in, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, not even `arrow` supports a timedelta with years :( probably because years are ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

You can feel awkward when you read it. I felt when I wrote.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from math import ceil

import parsedatetime

time_str = "1 year 26 weeks 1 day 23 hours 29 minutes"

cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
td: timedelta = cal.parseDT(time_str)[0] - datetime.now()
print(ceil(td.total_seconds()))
```

Answer is right, 47431740. I'm afraid, it's the best. [Used library](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime).

Comment: Note, this seems to rely on `parsedatetime` parsing that string as 1 year 26 weeks 1 day 23 hours 29 minutes, *from now*. This may not play well with leap years

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, good catch. Btw, I'm not sure how leap years should be handled at all. We can assume the beginning of the world in Jan 1, 1970 00:00 UTC or else :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use https://duckling.wit.ai/ to extract time entities from your string. There is dockerized version of it at: https://hub.docker.com/r/rasa/duckling

It also has a python wrapper: https://github.com/FraBle/python-duckling

But I prefer the dockerized version cause it's easy to use.

Comment: Are you sure? In the link provided, it fails to parse the OP's string.

Comment: Well for starters, it is *enormous overkill* for what the OP is doing, and doesn't even accomplish what the OP needs. Read their question

Comment: You haven't used it, how do you say it does not work? Do you alway look into demos for answers?

Comment: *The OP isn't asking for a library to parse that string*. Parsing that string is trivial, and doesn't require some dockerized NLP algorithm. You can do it trivially with a simple regex, or heck, probably even more simply. But if you claim this is a solution, then you need to provide that *in the question itself*

Comment: If by NLP you mean some machine learning or deep learning model, it is not. Duckling time parsing works by regex and regex can also be NLP. So read more on it.